# Commonjs library's index.ts as external module

Tags: typescript, npm, commonjs

I need some guidance to correctly develop reusable commonjs library (npm package).
Lets say the library structure is the following:

```
—lib
——Helper.ts
——Serialization.ts
——meta
——— Entity.ts
—index.ts
```

And so on. Each file is external module.

Now I need to create entry file (say index.ts) that will expose functionality of the library and will serve as entry point.
Here I can’t wrap my head around the way to create it. I would like to keep the nested structure without flattening it by exporting everything:

```
export * from './lib/Helper’;
export * from './lib/Serialization’;
export * from './lib/meta/Entity’;
…
```

Cause this will remove logical grouping and can in the future lead to possible name conflicts

I have also tried to have index.ts like this:

```
import {Helper} from './lib/Helper';
import * as Serialization from './lib/Serialization';
import * as Decorators from './lib/meta/Decorators';

let core = {
    Helper: Helper,
    Serialization: Serialization,
    Meta: {
        Entity: Entity,
    }
}

export default core;
```

It works perfect until I come to consume imported types like this:

```
import Core from ’nameOfTheNpmPackage';

let Entity = Core.Meta.Entity;

function f(e: Entity)//<—This produce error cannot find name ‘Entity'
{

}
```

As they are not in the type declaration space (is there a way of copying them there if they are not in namespace?)

Another option I have tried is generating single d.ts file for the whole library by using outFile + amd. But that file is not an external module.

So my question is  - how is it possible to write index.ts so that it will be external module and export all functionality exposed by library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One day of wasted time and I've come up with ugly solution.
To keep nested structure of the exported commonjs library you must inside each 'level' put its own `index.ts` that will aggregate and reexport all functionality of the same 'level'. For my sample above it will look like:

`—lib
——Helper.ts
——Serialization.ts
——meta
——— index.ts
——— Entity.ts
—index.ts`

Where root index.ts:

```
export * from './lib/Helper';
export * from './lib/Serialization';

import * as S from './lib/Serialization'; //This is case where one file contains several exported classes that we want to keen as separate module
export {S as Serialization};

import * as Meta from './lib/meta/index';
export {Meta};
```

And meta/index.ts:

```
export * from './Entity';
```

I would be really glad to know if this common(?) task is possible to solve without extra files per 'level'.