# Referencing decoupled modules with SystemJs

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I have two web apps developed with TypeScript that use some shared code.

For example, in `apps/app1/components/app1.component.ts` I have import statements to the shared code, e.g.,

```
import {ClassA} from '../../../shared/classA';
import {ClassB} from '../../../shared/classB';
```

similarly in `apps/app2/components/app2.component.ts` I have the same import statements, i.e.

```
import {ClassA} from '../../../shared/classA';
import {ClassB} from '../../../shared/classB';
```

where `ClassA` and `ClassB` reside at `apps/shared/ClassA` and `apps/shared/ClassB` respectively.

Currently, to load these shared modules in the browser, I have to update both `apps/app1/systemjs.config.js` and `apps/app2/systemjs.config.js` with the following map and packages statements,

```
map: {
  'classA':    'apps/shared',
  'classB':    'apps/shared
},
packages: {
  'classA':    {main: 'classA', defaultExtension: 'js'},
  'classB':    {main: 'classB', defaultExtension: 'js'}
}
```

This is fine if I just have two classes (`classA` and `classB`) but starts to become more difficult to maintain as the number of classes in `apps/shared` grows. Is there any way that I can tell the systemJs to load all the modules from `apps/shared` in a single statement? Something like

```
map: {
  'shared':    'apps/shared'
},
packages: {
  'shared':    {main: 'shared', defaultExtension: 'js'}
}
```

whilst maintaining the relative module resolution used in my TypeScript source (i.e. the import statements above)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem would be to arrange your shared code in the standalone module like the ones used for node.js:

1. Make a root folder for your library
2. In the root folder create index.ts file where you will expose all required classes ([example](https://github.com/magnetnation/mgCore/blob/master/index.ts))
3. In systemjs config map only index.ts

index.ts can look something like this:

```
export * from './lib/ClassA';
export * from './lib/ClassB';
```

If required you can also expose this way nested structure of your shared classes as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935552/commonjs-librarys-index-ts-as-external-module)

Yes you will have to maintain at least one extra `index.ts` file. But on the other hand you will need to do the class 'mapping' only there and only once.

Hope this will be of any help to you.